# Browsers ignoring single CSS file

Tags: css, parsing, browser, paint

Not sure how to really categorize this question, but on [this page](http://staging.hitgrid.com), the file http://d1el287zd12c0j.cloudfront.net/assets/hitgrid-0a8239a14fba0de87431c06cd75774f3.css seems to be completely ignored by browsers. It appears to load successfully and no different than any other css file on the page, but the styles in it are simply not applied to the page.

The content-type, encoding and everything appears to be working as expected. Roughly the same content "applies" fine on my local installation of the app.

I'm at a loss as to what's going on here.

Comment: It is working dude. i checked from inspect element..there is style including from this css file

Comment: Yep, I can see the file being fetched successfully in my inspector as well. The styles from that file are simply not being applied to the page, however. There should be a green header at the top, for example.

Comment: @sheldonnbbaker All the styles are being applied just fine... what are you talking about

Comment: Well that means then that it is happening for some people and not others. I've confirmed that this issue is happening with multiple people on different OS's and browsers on different networks, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Agree with Divyesh, styles are coming from this css and tested in chrome and ff too. Might be any other issue..inspect and catch that.

Answer (score -1):

I just check it out and everything went right.
Try to make the filename shorter in the CDN. Large names tend to make error in some way or maybe check if no other stylesheet is interfering with the styles

If that didn't work, answer these questions and Ill try to git it a try again

1. Which OS are you using?

   ### 2. Are you using wordpress?

Comment: stylesheets depend on os?? and what difference it will make if he is using wordpress?? and why in BOLD??